# How to properly define a Controller in Spring MVC compared to a JavaFX Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javafx, model-view-controller

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the differences between a JavaFX Controller and a Spring MVC Controller. I came from a JavaFX background and I have seen many differences between a Spring MVC Controller vs a JavaFX Controller and I am currently working with Spring MVC.
There are important differences between them, for example, in JavaFX, each fxml view has its own controller e.g. LoginViewController.java with loginview.fxml, RegisterViewController.java and registerview.fxml.

This is the code of a simple ToDo List in JavaFX to be more clear in my question:

ToDoListViewController.java:

```
public class ToDoListViewController {

    // private properties tied to the fxml view via @FXML annotation

    private List<TodoItem> todoItems;

    @FXML
    private ListView<TodoItem> todoListView;

    @FXML
    private TextArea itemDetailsTextArea;
    
    // ...

    

    public void initialize() {

       // code to initialize stuff
       // ...
    }


    @FXML
    public void showUpdateItemDialog() {
         //get the item to be updated
        // do stuff to update item
       // ....
    }

}
```

This Controller is tied to a todolistview.fxml, which I think is pretty straight forward.

Now in Spring, I have seen some controllers been oriented by the view and other by routes and it kind of confuses me. I have seen controllers like:

HomeController.java: (View Oriented)

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main-menu";
    }

}
```

CustomerController.java: (Route Oriented)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {
    
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
    
    public CustomerController(CustomerDAO customerDAO) {
        this.customerDAO = customerDAO;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model theModel) {
        
        // get the customers from the dao
        
        
        // add the customers to the model
        
        return "list-customers";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String addCustomer() {
        // return the jsp view to add a new customer
        
        return "customer-form";
    }

   // same goes for get by id, update and delete

   //...
}
```

Which is the best way to understand these differences? Which approach to use in Spring MVC? View oriented, Route oriented? Thanks for reading!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "oriented by view" or "by route". The [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types) is pretty clear about the various ways to provide the response. Personally, I usually end up going with `ModelAndView` most of the time in HTML-based applications, but that depends on the situation. (Side note: Use Thymeleaf instead of JSP. It's much friendlier.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks for your answer! sorry if I was not clear! for example, in Spring MVC the first Controller, HomeController.java just maps the home page (main-menu.jsp), just like in JavaFX, a view with its corresponding controller. In the second case, it appends to the URI /customer/list, handling different views, like list-customers.jsp, and /customer/add which returns another view which is customer-form.jsp. As I see, it is more route oriented, not view oriented, and I'm confused by that. Sorry if I can't be more clear I'm trying!

Comment: Ah, okay, in that case: Yes, Spring MVC dispatches based on routes (specifically _mappings_, which can also include additional rules like parameter filters or content-type), and you tell it what view to render. It's very common for a single controller to render different views depending on different conditions (such as errors), so in your response you provide those instructions.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot! Now I better understand the differences!

Comment: The application of MVC to a standalone thick-client desktop application is very different to the application of MVC to a web application, primarily because a web application has to sit on top of the HTTP request-response cycle. Until you have a lot of experience with both (when you'll start to see the abstract similarities between them), I'd recommend treating them as two completely distinct ideas, and learning them each in isolation.

Comment: @James_D Thank you very much for the suggestion! I'll take notes on this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on requirement,
for example:

In your case,
if you want to access anything directly, (as homepage) you can go with view oriented one.

and if anything you want the access the like CUSTOMERS , so in your case,
you can use view orientation, for example for viewing customer you can just create a method with just "/customerList" and you will also get the required result, but every time for the customers you will need to do this for everything,
Instead what you can do is
Use route mapping since the (customer)feature establishes a route with it's creation, so you can use route mapping, as you have post in second example,
in that case all the request with "/customer" will come there and then will get to the exact method which you want(have written in the method's mapping). It is good for end mapping and can use  to pass parameter id needed.

So it all depends on requirement and level of code one is writing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! all comments and your specific answer solved my issue understanding the difference between the way JavaFX and Spring MVC treats the MVC pattern!

Answer (score 1):

Route oriented is a good way of dealing with endpoints in spring MVC. This way gives a good look to our code, Our code looks more organized and easier to understand. Route-oriented ways also provide additional rules like parameter filters and content type.